# Bad floating point accuracy with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a solution for a mathematical problem that looks like this (sorry for the formatting, that's what PyCharm is doing):

```
sigma = (wf_s[0] * u ** 4 + wf_s[1] * u ** 3 * v + wf_s[2] * u ** 3 + wf_s[3] * u ** 2 * v ** 2 + wf_s[
                4] * u ** 2 * v + wf_s[5] * u ** 2 + wf_s[6] * u * v ** 3 + wf_s[7] * u * v ** 2 + wf_s[8] * u * v + wf_s[
                         9] * u + wf_s[10] * v ** 4 + wf_s[11] * v ** 3 + wf_s[12] * v ** 2 + wf_s[13] * v + wf_s[14]) / (
                                wf_s[15] * u ** 4 + wf_s[16] * u ** 3 * v + wf_s[17] * u ** 3 + wf_s[18] * u ** 2 * v ** 2 +
                                wf_s[19] * u ** 2 * v + wf_s[20] * u ** 2 + wf_s[21] * u * v ** 3 + wf_s[22] * u * v ** 2 +
                                wf_s[23] * u * v + wf_s[24] * u + wf_s[25] * v ** 4 + wf_s[26] * v ** 3 + wf_s[
                                    27] * v ** 2 + wf_s[28] * v + wf_s[29])

sigma = sqrt(sigma)

x1 = (wf_x1[0] * u ** 2 * sigma + wf_x1[1] * u ** 2 + wf_x1[2] * u * v * sigma + wf_x1[3] * u * v + wf_x1[
                4] * u * sigma + wf_x1[5] * u + wf_x1[6] * v ** 2 * sigma + wf_x1[7] * v ** 2 + wf_x1[8] * v * sigma +
                  wf_x1[9] * v + wf_x1[10] * sigma + wf_x1[11]) / (
                             wf_x1[12] * u ** 2 + wf_x1[13] * u * v + wf_x1[14] * u + wf_x1[15] * v ** 2 + wf_x1[16] * v +
                             wf_x1[17])

x2 = (wf_x2[0] * u ** 2 * sigma + wf_x2[1] * u ** 2 + wf_x2[2] * u * v * sigma + wf_x2[3] * u * v + wf_x2[
                4] * u * sigma + wf_x2[5] * u + wf_x2[6] * v ** 2 * sigma + wf_x2[7] * v ** 2 + wf_x2[8] * v * sigma +
                  wf_x2[9] * v + wf_x2[10] * sigma + wf_x2[11]) / (
                             wf_x2[12] * u ** 2 + wf_x2[13] * u * v + wf_x2[14] * u + wf_x2[15] * v ** 2 + wf_x2[16] * v +
                             wf_x2[17])

y1 = (wf_y1[0] * u ** 2 * sigma + wf_y1[1] * u ** 2 + wf_y1[2] * u * v * sigma + wf_y1[3] * u * v + wf_y1[
                4] * u * sigma + wf_y1[5] * u + wf_y1[6] * v ** 2 * sigma + wf_y1[7] * v ** 2 + wf_y1[8] * v * sigma +
                  wf_y1[9] * v + wf_y1[10] * sigma + wf_y1[11]) / (
                             wf_y1[12] * u ** 2 + wf_y1[13] * u * v + wf_y1[14] * u + wf_y1[15] * v ** 2 + wf_y1[16] * v +
                             wf_y1[17])

y2 = (wf_y2[0] * u ** 2 * sigma + wf_y2[1] * u ** 2 + wf_y2[2] * u * v * sigma + wf_y2[3] * u * v + wf_y2[
                4] * u * sigma + wf_y2[5] * u + wf_y2[6] * v ** 2 * sigma + wf_y2[7] * v ** 2 + wf_y2[8] * v * sigma +
                  wf_y2[9] * v + wf_y2[10] * sigma + wf_y2[11]) / (
                             wf_y2[12] * u ** 2 + wf_y2[13] * u * v + wf_y2[14] * u + wf_y2[15] * v ** 2 + wf_y2[16] * v +
                             wf_y2[17])
```

This calculation is running relatively slow in Python so I wanted to increase the speed using numpy. The result looks like this:

```
u2 = u ** 2
u3 = u ** 3
u4 = u ** 4
v2 = v ** 2
v3 = v ** 3
v4 = v ** 4

uv_s = np.array((u4, u3 * v, u3, u2 * v2, u2 * v, u2, u * v3, u * v2, u * v, u, v4, v3, v2, v, 1))
sigma = np.dot(wf_s[:15], uv_s) / np.dot(wf_s[15:], uv_s)

sigma = sqrt(sigma)

uv_xy_n = np.array((u2 * sigma, u2, u * v * sigma, u * v, u * sigma, u, v2 * sigma, v2, v * sigma, v, sigma, 1))
uv_xy_d = np.array((u2, u * v, u, v2, v, 1))
x12 = np.dot(wf_x1[:12], uv_xy_n) / np.dot(wf_x1[12:], uv_xy_d)
x22 = np.dot(wf_x2[:12], uv_xy_n) / np.dot(wf_x2[12:], uv_xy_d)
y12 = np.dot(wf_y1[:12], uv_xy_n) / np.dot(wf_y1[12:], uv_xy_d)
y22 = np.dot(wf_y2[:12], uv_xy_n) / np.dot(wf_y2[12:], uv_xy_d)
```

In theory this works fine and runs 3 times faster than my first method but the accuracy of the results is horrible. In my case, x and y are in the hundreds and the second method produces results that differ up to 0.2 from the real result. This accuracy is of no use in my case. Plotting the results of the first method results in a perfect plot as expected. Plotting the results of the second method results in a super noisy plot.

Why is the accuracy of the numpy version so bad and how can I improve it?

Comment: Maybe try out if you can select a longer number type (np.longdouble)? (Whether it effectively uses this, depends on your system)  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html

Comment: One problem is that numpy always computes pow(base,exponent). This is very slow for small exponents. As always in performance related questions provide some representative Input data. (one function with input and output, Input data can be some arrays with random numbers...)